# Replace multiple ids in a path after validation [Golang]

Tags: string, go, replace

I have a path delimited by `/`and an expectation to have multiple ids I want to replace with a constant value. The issue I am facing is that once it validates the first id, it performs the replacement and stops. My assumption is that I should be having some sort of do while in Golang (see this [resource](https://yourbasic.org/golang/do-while-loop/) - I know there is no such a construct in Go) and I have attempted at using:

```
for true {       
      // do something
}
```

but still only the first id is replaced. Any idea? Thank you

Here is my Go Playground [example](https://go.dev/play/p/HGWdxlDWJQ2) with the original implementation

Comment: You are returning the SubstituteById function on the first occurrence of a match. Instead, you should accumulate the changes and only return the function in the end for the entire for loop. There's no need for a do-while or any other loop here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you early `return` after first match. Since you iterating parts of path you should assign result of `strings.Replace()` to a variable and return after for loop. Assign to `path` instead of returning and it should work as expected.

```
func SubstituteById(path string, repl string) string {
    ids := strings.Split(path, "/")
    for _, id := range ids {
        if fastuuid.ValidHex128(id) {
            path = strings.Replace(path, id, repl, -1)
        }
    }
    return path
}
```